# Angularjs routing with variable appended

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Basically, this is a social sort of application that I am working on.

So, for this app to work, the '/home' state shows a list of users. The 'friends/X' (X being user id) shows the profile of that user.

So, here is my app with the ng controller in the element:

`ng-click="profile({{friend.id}})"`

This hooks up and sends a function call to my controller "HomeController" which is currently in "/home". My problem is, how do I open a new state and pass a variable, the friend.id in this case to the state?

Thank you :)

EDIT:
Basically I want to know how a function "profile" can capture the id, then call the new state and send it the variable id of friend.id

EDIT 2:
Basically, in the profile function which is in the "HomeController" it will accept a ID as a perameter, so for example "1", and it will use the value it received and send the application to a NEW state for example now the new state is going to be "ProfileController" and it will be "/home/profile" or something like that, and it will pass along the "1" into the url, like so: "/home/profile/1".

Comment: omit those curly braces: `ng-click="profile(friend.id)"`

Comment: ng-click="profile(friend.id)"

Comment: The curly braces are for a id I am retrieving from a variable, or at least that's what I think you call it. But my main problem is telling my new state what the id is.

Comment: Basically I want to know how a function "profile" can capture the id, then call the new state and send it the variable id of friend.id

Comment: Would you explain what you want to achieve in your `profile` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this inside a function, you should use the [`$location` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#url) to change the URL. Then the route will update, and the *profile* controller can take over.

```
<a ng-click="profile(friend.id)">{{friend.name}}</a>
```

... And in the controller:

```
$scope.profile = function(id) {
    $location.url('/home/profile/' + id);
};
```

However, unless you need to do something with the click *before* changing the route, you can probably just do it with an href:

```
<a ng-href="#/home/profile/{{friend.id}}">{{friend.name}}</a>
```

If you stick to this method and leave it to the routing mechanism to choose the right controller, then your user will be able to copy/bookmark/jump to that URL directly, and use the back/forward buttons in the browser.

Use the [`$routeProvider` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) to tell AngularJS which controller to use based on the URL. For example (this should go in your module's [`.config`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#config)):

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/home/profile/:friendId', {
        templateUrl: 'profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileController'
    })
    ...etc
```

Then you can use [`$routeParams`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) in `ProfileController` to get the current `friendId` parameter.

Comment: About the back/forward buttons, only in the second case they will be able to, right? Which isn't much of a problem in my case as this isnt a very security intensive app. But Holy COW! I am SO DUMB! That is one of he EASIEST methods to do it! Thank you!!!

Comment: Right, the back/forward buttons will only work if the URL changes. Maybe you can do it programmatically(?), but it will be more difficult.